# How to change the stroke width in a CareKit graph?

Tags: ios, swift, carekit

I'm trying to display a graph in my app using CareKit-UI. But the default stroke width is huge and I'd like to change it. I tried to use `OCKDimensionStyler` and overriding the `lineWidth1` property, but it failed at updating the graph's main line.

[image]

Chart view declaration:

```swift
let chartView = OCKCartesianChartView(type: .line)

chartView.headerView.titleLabel.text = "Doxylamine"

chartView.graphView.dataSeries = [
    OCKDataSeries(values: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2], title: "Doxylamine")
]
```

Answer (score 2):

This property isn't editable using an `OCKStyler`, but by setting the `size` property of `OCKDataSeries`.

Here's an updated version of the code:

```swift
let chartView = OCKCartesianChartView(type: .line)

chartView.headerView.titleLabel.text = "Doxylamine"

var series = OCKDataSeries(values: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2], title: "Doxylamine")
series.size = 2
chartView.graphView.dataSeries = [series]
```

This allows you to have multiple series on the same graph, with different stroke width for each series.

[image]